# How to read a property from twitter api using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created a very basic Angular application in which I'll simply fetch my twitter statuses using Twitter API. My problem is related to the JSON response that I'm getting. Here's my code:

**twitter-timeline.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TwitterserviceService } from '../twitterservice.service';

@Component({
  ...
})


export class TwitterTimelineComponent implements OnInit {

  myTimeline: any;

  constructor(private api: TwitterserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTwitterTimeline();
  }

  getTwitterTimeline(): void {
    this.api.getTimeline()
      .subscribe(
        myTimeline => {
          this.myTimeline = myTimeline;
          console.log(this.myTimeline);
        }
      )
   } 
}
```

This is the JSON response that I'm getting:

```
{
  "statuses": [
    {
      "created_at": "Mon May 06 20:01:29 +0000 2019",
      "id": 1125490788736032770,
      "id_str": "1125490788736032770",
      "text": "Today's new update means that you can finally add Pizza Cat to your Retweet",
      "truncated": true,
      "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "symbols": [],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "urls": [
          {
            "url": "https...some web link",
            "expanded_url": "https...twitter.com/i/web/status/11254907", <---------------THIS I WANT
            "display_url": "twitter.com/i/web/status/1…",
            "indices": [
              117,
              140
            ]
          }
        ]
      }, ...
```

In HTML I want to read this property i.e. `expanded_url` and pass it to a simple anchor tag so that the user may go to that link.

**twitter-timeline.component.html**

```
<div class="container card" *ngFor="let tweets of myTimeline.data">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 image-column">
        <div class="twitter-logo-wrapper">
          <img class="twitter-logo" src="assets/images/icons/twitter-icon.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 text-column">
        <p class="screen-name">{{tweets.user.screen_name}}<br>
          <span class="user-status">{{tweets.user.description}}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <span class="likes-count">{{tweets.user.followers_count}}</span>
          <span class="date-of-post">{{tweets.created_at}}</span>
          <span>
            <a href="{{tweets.urls.expanded_url}}" target="_blank">
              <button class="btn btn-info">Read</button>
            </a>
           </span>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TwitterTimelineComponent...: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'expanded_url' of undefined
```

I also tried adding index in html as:

```
<div class="container card" *ngFor="let tweets of myTimeline.data; let i=index">

...

<a [attr.href]="tweets.urls[i].expanded_url" target="_blank">
```

Comment: quick remark : in the example json, `urls` is an array, containing one object. so the correct thing to do would be rather `tweets.urls[0].expanded_url` . But the cause of your error is different, becasue apparentlly `tweets.urls` looks undefined, as per the error message.

Comment: urls is an array of objects, you probably need `tweets.urls[0].expanded_url`.

Comment: Try displaying just `{{tweets.urls | json }}`, I bet you it is undefined. But if it does become defined later on, you can try using the safe navigation operator (?) like so `{{tweets?.urls?.expanded_url}}`.

Comment: also, if `mytimeline.data` is the example json you posted, it's not an array, so you should not do a `for` on it. at the end, that would be something like `theResponse.statuses[0].entities.urls[0].expanded_url`

Comment: @AliF50, yes you're absolutely correct. It is undefined.

Comment: @Tanzeel : what does `{{tweets | json }}` shows ?

Comment: Sorry everyone. My API limit has exceeded the hit rate. I'll have to wait for next 15 mins. :-(

Comment: @Pac0,  `tweets.urls[0].expanded_url` is giving me `ERROR TypeError: "_v.context.$implicit.urls is undefined"`

Comment: @AliF50, `{{tweets |  json}}` is not giving any error but also it is not taking me anywhere. It justs opens a new tab with `localhost:4200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start from `expanded_url` and so on and to be sure you are selecting the right property use brackets `['']` :

Example :   `tweets['entities']['urls'][0]['expanded_url']`

```
<a *ngIf="tweets['entities']['urls']?.length > 0" href="{{tweets['entities']['urls'][0]['expanded_url']}}" target="_blank">
   <button class="btn btn-info">Read</button>
</a>
```

Comment: putting accessors in bracket is the same as doing `tweets.entities.urls[0].expanded_url`, I don't see how the brackets would really help more.

Comment: sometimes you face properties like this expanded-url in that case you are forced to use brackets, i added it just for info.

Comment: Your solution is working. But also on console i'm getting this: `ERROR TypeError: "_v.context.$implicit.entities.urls[0] is undefined"`

Comment: Can you please check the problem. I tried using `?` with your solution. But still getting error.

Comment: just add an *ngIf="tweets['entities']['urls']" in the element where the href is

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you but again i've started getting this: `ERROR TypeError: "_v.parent.context.$implicit.entities.urls[0] is undefined"`  :-(

Comment: Now only first `Read` button  is showing. there's no error but only one button is there that is for the very first iteration only.

Comment: No Sir wait. I noticed that there's read button for only few. I think this is because there isn't any `extended_url` value in the response itself. Give me 1 min. Let me quickly check the entire response on console. I'll get back to you.

Comment: This solution was wonderful Sir. Can you please explain me a little bit. Give me some idea then I'll do further research on my own. :-)